# Añadir class según la url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, css3

Tengo una web hecha por (modulos "header.php , footer.php etc...")  necesito saber de que manera puedo implementar una classe según la url en la que estén
Ejemplo

```
<li><a href="index.php">Inicio </a></li>
<li><a href="patatas.php">Recetas</a></li>
<li><a href="pure.php">Pure</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
```

Pues si en ese momento en la url que están es miweb.es/pure.php que la class class="active" se ponga `<li class="active"><a href="pure.php">Pure</a></li>`

Comment: Bienvenido te invito a leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que te interesa es saber la URI actual, puedes recurrir a las variables [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) en este caso en concreto a la clave `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` donde se almacena la URI que se empleó para acceder a la página. Por ejemplo: `/index.html`.

Modificando así la lista, te añadiría la clase activa que coincidan el `href` y la `URI` en la que te encuentras:

```
<li <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php") echo "class='active'"?>><a  href="index.php">Inicio </a></li>
<li <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/patatas.php") echo "class='active'"?>><a href="patatas.php">Recetas</a></li>
<li <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/pure.php") echo "class='active'"?>><a href="pure.php">Pure</a></li>
<li <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/blog.php") echo "class='active'"?>><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
```